# How can I change the styling of a progress bar on iOS using Ionic?

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework

I was playing around with the `SCSS` and `Variable` Classes in order too customize my Progress bar the same as my theme.

The progress bar styling is Blue and White and when adding styling it changes to Green & Grey no matter what styling I use.

I used these two Webkit Pseudo classes:

```
-webkit-progress-bar

-webkit-progress-value
```

"It worked in the browser but not on the device."

Is there any special way to do this or am I just missing it.

**EDIT**

**HTML**

```
 <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="navtoPhases()">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col"><h2>Chassis Prep</h2></div>
         <div class="col"><progress class="progress" max="100" value="{{ ph[0].Chassis }}"></progress></div>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
```

**SCSS**

```
progress.progress{
   // -webkit-progress-bar: #ffc900 !important ; 
   // -webkit-progress-value:#ef473a !important ;
   color:#33cd5f;
   background-color:#3299E6;
    width: 50;
}
```

The changes can be seen on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oco1bu12/) page I am using Google, other browsers may defer like fox and opera.

Comment: What progress bar are we talking about here? Could you post some code examples to illustrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Dexter Yes I Edited my Question with the coding.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue, if I apply the same styling to a progress bar it works just fine on iOS. I get a progress bar with a gray background and a green bar to indicate the progress. Is there any additional information you can provide that we can use to help you out? Are you sure that you are editing in the right file? Perhaps try to make other CSS changes and see if something happens on iOS.

Comment: Yes The Green and Grey also happens to me, that is the issue. for some reason without the styling the bar is blue and white and with the styling it is green and grey. but no matter what colour I try to change it to it stays green and grey? @Dexter Sorry my question is vague will EDIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice article [here](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/), that explains how you can override styling of progress bars in CSS. In the article, several ways of overriding the default styling of progress bars are discussed, but the only one you really need is the one for Chrome/Webkit, which I have posted below for your convenience.

```
progress[value] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #33cd5f;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #3299E6;
  border-radius: 2px; 
}
```